# Array sorting in Javascript with nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects which I need to sort in 2 ways as stated below:

1. Sort by alphabetical order using the country name.
2. Inside every country sort scores in ascending order.

Below is the array and what I have tried to do.

```js
//Structure of the Array
let allCountryScores=[
   {
      name: "Ethiopia", 
      scores:  [ {n: "Sub", s: 9990}, {n: "lucy", s: "4134234"}, {n: "DWH", s: 9999},  {n: "Hanif", s: 999999999} ]
    },     

]

//MY Code below

//Alphabetic ordering countries

let orderedCountries = allCountryScores.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
//Numeric ordering of scores
let orderedScores = orderedCountries.forEach(country => { country.scores.sort((a, b) => a.s > b.s) });
console.log(orderedScores);
```

In my console, I am getting undefined. What could be wrong with my code?

Comment: `forEach()` doesn't return anything. You also have no `return` statement in the `country => { ... }` function.

Comment: Also keep in mind that while the first sort does assign the sorted array to `orderedCountries` it is not a new array, but the mutated original array.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have done that but nothing has changed

Comment: @Barmar I have added the return keyword but my array is only sorting using the first criteria only

Comment: You also need to change `forEach` to `map`, since `forEach` doesn't return what the callback function returns.

Comment: @Barmar the problem with the map is that it will not return the country names

Comment: It will return whatever the callback function returns. The function should sort the `scores` property and then return the object.

Comment: Oooo ok now I understand your logic, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. `forEach` always returns `undefined`. You don't need the assignment on that line, just remove it. (You also don't need the assignment on the previous line, `sort` works on the array in place.)
2. You're not sorting the scores correctly, `a.s > b.s` doesn't return what `sort` expects from its callback (a negative number if `a` should come before `b`, a positive number if `a` should come after `b`, or `0` if their order doesn't matter). `a.s - b.s` does return that number.

Here's an updated version assuming you're happy to modify your original arrays:

```
//Alphabetic ordering countries
allCountryScores.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
//Numeric ordering of scores
allCountryScores.forEach(country => { country.scores.sort((a, b) => a.s - b.s) });
console.log(allCountryScores);
```

Live Copy:

```js
//Structure of the Array
let allCountryScores=[
   {
      name: "Ethiopia", 
      scores:  [ {n: "Sub", s: 9990}, {n: "lucy", s: "4134234"}, {n: "DWH", s: 9999},  {n: "Hanif", s: 999999999} ]
    },     

]

//Alphabetic ordering countries
allCountryScores.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
//Numeric ordering of scores
allCountryScores.forEach(country => { country.scores.sort((a, b) => a.s - b.s) });
console.log(allCountryScores);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If you want to create new arrays containing new objects with new arrays in them instead, you can do it like this:

```
const countries =
    allCountryScores.map(({name, scores}) => {
        // Copy and sort the scores
        scores = [...scores].sort((a, b) => a.s - b.s);
        // Return a new object
        return {name, scores};
    })
    // Sort that new array of countries
    .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
```

Live Copy:

```js
//Structure of the Array
let allCountryScores=[
   {
      name: "Ethiopia", 
      scores:  [ {n: "Sub", s: 9990}, {n: "lucy", s: "4134234"}, {n: "DWH", s: 9999},  {n: "Hanif", s: 999999999} ]
    },     

]

const countries =
    allCountryScores.map(({name, scores}) => {
        // Copy and sort the scores
        scores = [...scores].sort((a, b) => a.s - b.s);
        // Return a new object
        return {name, scores};
    })
    // Sort that new array of countries
    .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));

console.log(countries);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am now sorted

Comment: @KudahShambare - LOL! I see what you did there. :-D